# Close a Winforms opened by a web service vb .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, web-services

So I literally have 1 line of code in this web service that should be starting a desktop app that will do a lot of work. I chose the desktop app because the work could take 20+ hours, and if I was to choose just a web service the app pool recycling schedule could throw me a curve ball.

This is my web service

```
Process.Start("C:\ReTransPrograms\RateAnalytics\AnalyticsBatchRateDesktop.exe", arguments)
```

after the work is finished in the desktop app (winforms), in the background worker completed event, I've tried...

```
Application.Exit()
```

and..

```
me.close()
```

When I check the Task Manager after the work is completed, the App is still running. Am I missing something? Permissions? Security?

When I run the desktop app locally, it closes as it should when it's finished.

The AppPool is running as LocalSystem.

Comment: the app pool is very restricted to the directory the web service is running. So if your app is writing to a folder or the registry, it could be stuck.  Diagnose using sysinternal process app

Comment: It might be better to create a Windows service which does the processing and has some way of querying it for some sort of metric as to how far it has gone/expected time remaining. You then create some way of giving the Windows service a job.

Comment: I thought about that Andrew, but I need multiple instances of this program that's being started from the web service

Comment: Not writing to anything but a SQL database. I did make sure it had permissions to the SQL database. The entire app works perfectly, except it won't close when its done.

Comment: @TeddyHiggins The Windows service could start a new thread (or Task) for each instance of the task.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the process ID and kill it at close.

```
Private Sub Main()

    ProcessID = Process.Start("C:\ReTransPrograms\RateAnalytics\AnalyticsBatchRateDesktop.exe", arguments).ID

End Sub
```

When it's time to close call:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(ProcessID).Kill()
```

Comment: How likely is it to have a computer reuse a processID?

Comment: Process ID's are recycled as soon as the process closes.